# Dismissing all presented ViewControlelrs in a UINavigationController hierarchically

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I was looking for a way to dismiss all the modally presented viewControllers in a `UINavigationController` hierarchically without knowing the name of them. so I ended up to the while loop as follow:

**Swift**

```
while(navigationController.topViewController != navigationController.presentedViewController) {
      navigationController.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Objective-c**

```
while(![self.navigationController.topViewController isEqual:self.navigationController.presentedViewController]) {
    [self.navigationController.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I want to dismiss all the `presentedControllers` one by one till the `presentedViewController` and `topViewcontroller` become equal.

the problem is that the `navVC.presentedViewController` doesn't changed even after dismissing.

It remains still the same even after dismissing and I end up to an `infiniteLoop`.

Does anyone knows where is the problem?

Comment: I think your problem is dismiss presented view controller while notification is tapped from the user! Right? Can you explain why do you need to dismiss view controllers?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need to back to the topViewController of the NavigationController to be able to push the requestedViewController when the notification is tapped.

Comment: @Mina If so? You can do that by posting a notification to the view controller when remote or local notification is tapped. You should create an observer to it ( Presented View Controller ). And check: If current view controller is a presented view controller? And then you can dismiss it.

Comment: I don't get your point. Imagine that I don't know the presented viewController. there is about 50 viewControllers and I have no idea which ones are presented. and some times I have several modals on each others,

Comment: @Mina All of the view controllers are presented?

Comment: it depends, yes. but the problem is when I have 2 or 3 presentedViewController on each other when the push is received.

Comment: @Mina If you have too many presented view controllers? You should create an another window! I mean a `UIWindow`. With the new window you can do anything.

Comment: @Mina Check this this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47131085/6680583)

Comment: I found the answer. I can dismiss all presentedViewControllers on a navigation by:
```navVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)```

Answer (score 2):

In my case nothing works but:

```
func dismissToSelf(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    // Collecting presented
    var presentedVCs: [UIViewController] = []
    var vc: UIViewController? = presentedViewController
    while vc != nil {
        presentedVCs.append(vc!)
        vc = vc?.presentedViewController
    }

    // Dismissing all but first
    while presentedVCs.count > 1 {
        presentedVCs.last?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        presentedVCs.removeLast()
    }

    // Dismissing first with animation and completion
    presentedVCs.first?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: completion)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer. I can dismiss all `presentedViewControllers` on a navigationController by:

`navigationController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

It keeps the `topViewController` and dismiss all other modals.

Answer (score 0):

Form your question I understood that you want to dismiss all view controllers above the root view controller. For that you can do it like this:

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: No, My ```rootViewController``` is a ```UITabbarController```, as I mentioned in my question, I want to dismiss all ViewControllers which are modally presented on a ```UINavigationController``` which is on one of the tabs of the tabbar.

Answer (score 0):

Not need to used self.navigationController.presentedViewController.

Might be help! my code is as follows:
**Objective-c**

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

}];
// Or using this 

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```
-(void)dismissModalStack {
UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController;
while (vc.presentedViewController) {
    vc = vc.presentedViewController;
    [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see you have found the answer, and I've done this by another way.

You can create a BaseViewController(actually lots of app do that), and defined a property like 'presentingController' in appdelegate that indicate  the presenting ViewController, then in the viewWillAppear method, set the property so that it always indicate the top view controller.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{  

    AppDelegate *delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];  
    delegate.presentingController = self;    
}
```

All the class inherited from BaseViewController will call it. When you want to dismiss all the controller, just loop as follow:

```
- (void)clickButton:(id)sender {  

    AppDelegate *delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplicationsharedApplication]delegate];  

    if (delegate.presentingController)  
    {  
        UIViewController *vc =self.presentingViewController;  

        if ( !vc.presentingViewController )   return;  

        while (vc.presentingViewController)  
        {  
            vc = vc.presentingViewController;  
        }  

        [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YEScompletion:^{  

        }];  
    }  
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue of deleting/dismissing existing/previous push notification when a new push notification arrives where different pictures are sent as a push notification.
In my situation, using Swift 5, I wanted to delete/dismiss previous push notification and display a new push notification all by itself regardless whether the user acknowledged the previous notification or not (i.e. without user's acknowledgement).

I tried Kadian's recommendation with a minor change and it worked flawlessly.

Here is my NotificationDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
  func userNotificationCenter(
    _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])   
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(
    _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()

    defer { completionHandler() }
    guard response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier else {return}

    let payload = response.notification.request.content
    
    let pn = payload.body  
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: pn)

    //***Below cmd will erase previous push alert***
    self.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    //Below cmd will display a newly received push notification
    self.window!.rootViewController!.present(vc, animated: false)

  }
  }
```