# Present viewController from AppDelegate crashes/ empty screen

Tags: swift, pushviewcontroller

I am facing the issue that when I want to present a view programmatically my app crashes/ shows empty black view.

The opening of the vc happens when a user clicks on notifications.
I have a tabbar, a navigation controller and a view which is reachable from the first vc in the tabbar.

When I want to push the vc my app crashes, however when I delete everything in the viewDidLoad() in my to be pushed to vc ( ChatVC) my app displays the vc but empty and black.
My app delegate push code.
Its not about the chatvc, I tried every view controller I have and it crashes at the same point.

```
 let chatVc = AllChatsViewController()

        if let tabbarControler = window?.rootViewController as? MainTabBarController {
            tabbarControler.selectedIndex = 0

            //tabbarControler.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


            if let homeNav = tabbarControler.viewControllers?.first as? UINavigationController {
                homeNav.pushViewController(chatVc, animated: true)
                print(followerId)
            }
        }

    }
```

**Update**

```
  if let chatPartnerId = userInfo["chatPartnerId"] {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Chat", bundle: Bundle.main)
        guard let chatVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessageViewController") as? MessageViewController else {return}
        chatVC.userId = chatPartnerId as! String

        if let tabbarControler = window?.rootViewController as? MainTabBarController {
            tabbarControler.selectedIndex = 0

            tabbarControler.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


            if let homeNav = tabbarControler.viewControllers?.first as? UINavigationController {
                homeNav.pushViewController(chatVC, animated: true)

            }
        }
```

It now pushes as expected to the ViewController but neither viewDidLoad or any other function will be called, any Idea?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47131085/6680583

Comment: I tried this as well, it crashed when I set the self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried instead of
`let chatVc = AllChatsViewController()`
instantiate it from Storyboard? In storyboard find your viewController and vige it an identifier (i'll use chatVC). then 
`let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle Bundle.main)
let chatVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatVC")`

The reason is because if using the above method all your subviews get initiated and laid out automatically, as opposed to your method where you are required to do it yourself (which you probably haven't done hence the crash , and the fact that if you delete view did load lines that call your subviews it passes.)

Comment: Hey I have just copied the method from LetsBuildThatsApp guy but I will try yours again, did it before but maybe something wrong

Comment: well it worked in the first try, thanks I upvote yours!

Comment: I receive a userID from my notification and would like to set it to the userID in my ChatVC but chatVC.userId doesn't work, I can't access it

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but maybe try changing to this `guard let chatVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatVC") as?AllChatsViewController else{return}` then your chatVC will be of type AllCHatsViewController and it will know how to handle userId.