# Present UINavigationController from inside UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a quick question regarding instantiating a particular view controller from my AppDelegate. I am building a simple chat app that needs to respond when a user opens the app via a remote notification. The desired behavior of my app is that when the user taps this notification the application will open to that particular chat screen.

The basic flow of the app is as follows:

- The highest level UI component is a UITabBarController
- Inside this tab bar is a navigation controller
- Inside the nav controller is a view controller (let's call it the "list") which lists all the available chat windows
- Once a user taps on one of the rows of my tableview that lists the chats a new view controller is pushed. This view controller is the chat window which automatically hides the tab bar but keeps the back button of the nav controller
- When the user taps the back button it will return to the chat list and the tab bar will reappear

I am using the following code to get the correct chat screen to appear. I can tap the back button and it will return to the chat list as expected. The only problem is that the navigation controller isn't embedded in the tab controller. This code is being called from `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler`:

```
let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialVC : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatVC") as UIViewController
let detailVC : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatDetailVC") as UIViewController
let navContr = UINavigationController(rootViewController:initialVC)
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = navContr
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
initialVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
```

How can I configure my code so that the tab controller is the top level of the stack? It's labelled "TabController" in my storyboard.

Comment: You need to perform each navigation manually when user tap on notification.

Comment: Try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47131085/6680583)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a **flag** which determine if user comes from notification tap or normally launch

```
struct NotificationEvent {
    static var isFromNotification = false
}
```

The stack of controller is -

> TabBarController->UINavigationController->ChatListViewController->ChatDetailViewController

In AppDelegate `func userNotificationCenter` -

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabViewController") as! TabViewController//Your Tabbarcontroller
NotificationEvent.isFromNotification = true//recognize is from notification 
window?.rootViewController = vc
```

**ChatListViewController**

```
class ChatListViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if NotificationEvent.isFromNotification  {
            openChatDetailScreen()//Jumps to that chat screen
            NotificationEvent.isFromNotification = false
        }
    }
    @IBAction func tapsOnChatList(_ sender: UIButton) {//consider it as didselect method in your tableView
        openChatDetailScreen()
    }

    func openChatDetailScreen() {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatDetailViewController") as! ChatDetailViewController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Or** instead of `NotificationEvent.isFromNotification` you can also check with `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification`/observer of notification event in particular viewcontroller.