# userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) not be called when a notification action is selected

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to get actionable notifications working and I have gotten the actions to display when the notification is expanded, but I cannot get the delegate function to be called when I select an action. I am declaring `self.notificationCenter.delegate = self` in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`, and, if I'm understanding correctly, when an action is selected it should call `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`, passing in the `UNNotificationResponse` object. But that method never gets triggered in my code. Any ideas why that may be happening?

Comment: Have you created an action to it? If so, you will need to check an action identifier first. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47131085/6680583) one

Comment: @Mannopson This ended up not being the issue, but I will look into this and see if it is still something I need to handle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. To handle notifications with content you have to add a service extension as a new target in the project. The last thing I ran was the service extension so the debugger wasn't stopping at breakpoints in the main app. I didn't know service extensions are essentially treated like completely separate apps. Since I was still in the process of working on the content of that method, what was in there was not working and it was hitting the breakpoints, so I thought it was not calling that function like it should.

Answer (score 0):

The method you have mentioned above gets called as soon as you receive notification.

The method which is executed after clicking on action on notification is,
application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:

Comment: That method is deprecated. According to the Apple Programming Guide `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` is the delegate method that gets called when the action is selected.

Comment: The method I posted is the new one. You can check this link 'https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623068-application'